# Nginx redirect on query parameter, how to avoid loops

Tags: nginx, redirect

- I'm trying to accomplish the following: listen to all incoming requests, and if a certain query parameter exists, redirect to another location with that query parameter set.

My problem is, that I cannot avoid triggering redirect loops, because ngnix keeps hitting the query parameter rule and thus redirecting again.

Example:

```
# the redirect location
location /redirect {
    # do nothing, this should be accepted
}
# listen for myparam query parameter and redirect to /redirect
location / {
   if($arg_myparam) {
      return http://mysite/redirect/?myparam=$myparam;
   }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to direct all page requests containing "myparam" query parameter to the /redirect route.

I can see why this triggers a loop, but I cannot for the love of God see how I can avoid it... any help is greatly appreciated

Cheers

Comment: Put the If statement inside a block `location /`

Comment: Hi @Drifter104, I've tried that as well.. will try again and if that helps, will modify the question.. thanks

Comment: Can you include an example of an original url?

Comment: would be something like http://mysite.mydomain.com/whatever/girlfriend?myparam=1111111

Comment: I've tried to put the listening directive inside a location block, but this still triggers a loop.. ideally the first /redirect location should be caught and then nothing else happen.. but it seems like the location / is still processed somehow.hmmm

Comment: You have a syntax error which will prevent `nginx` from loading the revised configuration (which actually works ok). There is a missing space separator after `if` and the returned parameter should be `?myparam=$arg_myparam` or just simply `?$args`